How do I get the size (in bytes) of an OpenCL buffer?
I'm using the OpenCL C++ API bindings, a.k.a. cl.hpp. I have a buffer, i.e. a cl::buffer. A buffer is constructed passing a size, and it isn't supposed to be just some raw pointer. I was expecting a Buffer::size() or Buffer::num_bytes() as a method, but that just doesn't exist.
So, how do I obtain my buffer's size?

OpenCL buffers are held, under the hood, using an opaque handle; and one can request information about a buffer using some querying mechanism. It is a bit cumbersome, and unfortunately - the Buffer.cpp implementation leaves something to be desired - as it uses an out-parameter.
Consider writing a small helper function:
size_t size_in_bytes(cl::Buffer const & buffer) {
    size_t size = 0;
    cl_int result = buffer.getInfo(CL_MEM_SIZE, &soize);
    if (err != CL_SUCCESS) throw cl::Error(err, __func__);
    return result;
}

If you want to know what goes on under the hoold, its:the a the (non-C++, underlying) OpenCL API function clGetMemObjectInfo:
extern CL_API_ENTRY cl_int CL_API_CALL
clGetMemObjectInfo(
    cl_mem           memobj,
    cl_mem_info      param_name,
    size_t           param_value_size,
    void *           param_value,
    size_t *         param_value_size_ret);

In your case, the param_name will be CL_MEM_SIZE and the return parameter is param_value.
